# VS Code indenting substituting spaces for tabs?

Tags: visual-studio-code, tabs, space, auto-indent

I am developing in Python via remote-SSH in VS-Code. After a particularly hasty shutdown due to physical issues with the remote server where I commanded a shutdown from within the terminal, I came back to VS-Code to discover that all of the formatting in my remote workspace was entirely screwed up.

Specifically, pressing Tab to indent would invariably give four spaces despite indicating "Indent Using Tabs" with size 4, in both the User and Remote settings tabs. What's even more confusing is that when I insert a newline, *tabs are substituted by spaces*, i.e. if I am entering a new-line on a twice-indented line, the next line is indented by two spaces instead of two tabs, etc.
[VS Code substitutes a space for a tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGupf.png)

I am not running many extensions, just all the Microsoft Python extensions, as well as IntelliCode. I am not running Prettier.

Attempts to fix it include various combinations and permutations of forcing the entire document to indent using tabs, converting all the spaces to tabs, and converting all of the tabs to spaces in some vague hope of resetting whatever widget is broken within VS-Code, none of which have had any effect.

If anyone has encountered this before or knows exactly what is causing this issue, I would be extremely grateful.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. For some reason Python Indent was installed in my local extensions, and it was auto-correcting the indents. Closing the issue in 2 days